# Getting restricted data from a website that is only available after logging in

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

I have been trying to download data from www.trademap.org
Export data is available in HS2,HS4 and HS6 format. One HS2 is divided into many HS4 which is divided further into HS6.

I have been able to extract data on the web page using beautiful soup. The issue is that I want data at HS6 level while without logging in data till HS4 is available only.

To counter this issue, I would need to first login to trademap from python.

Can anybody tell how would it be possible.

One of the codes I took help from was this:

```
from webbot import Browser 
web = Browser()
web.go_to('www.trademap.org') 
web.click('Login')
web.type('example@gmail.com' , into='ctl00$PageContent$Login1_UserName')

web.type('examplepassword' , into='ctl00$PageContent$Login1_Password' , id='PageContent_Login1_LabelPassword') # specific selection
web.click('ctl00$PageContent$Login1_Button',id='PageContent_Login1_DivButton')
```

But this has not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59333506/module-object-not-callable-when-trying-to-log-into-webpage-using-requests-po) and, obviously, with the corrections made by the answer.